# Change path_names for all of resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I change a rails resource route so that each one is prepended by a parameter that needs to be passed? The tricky part however, is that the parameter needs to be passed after the controller, but before the action.

Something like so:

```
/posts/:type/new
/posts/:type/edit
```

and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this, where you have seperate routes which route to the same controller:

```
namespace :posts do
  resources :public, controller: "posts"
  resources :private, controller: "posts"
end
```

This gives you `/posts/public/*` and `/posts/private/*`.